# RSelenium : connecting to the server

Tags: r, selenium, rselenium

This is my first experience on RSelenium. The `checkForServer()` command does not work !

```
checkForServer()
Error: checkForServer is now defunct. Users in future can find the function
    in file.path(find.package("RSelenium"), "examples/serverUtils"). The
    recommended way to run a selenium server is via Docker. Alternatively
    see the RSelenium::rsDriver function.
```

As it recommend, I have tried `rsDriver` :

```
library(RSelenium)
> rD1 <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome", port = 3987L)
checking Selenium Server versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking chromedriver versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking geckodriver versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking phantomjs versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.
[1] "Connecting to remote server"
No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.
$id
[1] NA
```

But something is wrong here, what that `No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.` means ?
How should I know that I have the stand alone server running or not ?!

Comment: You should try with: `library(RSelenium)
driver <- rsDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port=4445L, browser=c("firefox"), version = "latest")`

Comment: Same problem, any solution?